# AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will be very grateful for your help. I get an error message, stated below, from this part of my code, which I want to use, to elucidate differentially expressed genes in conditions of Crohn's disease and ulcerative colitis, from affymetrix microarray analysis(raw data link is https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser?acc=GDS1615). BUT when I run this code:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

"""
Read in a SOFT format data file.  The following values can be exported:

GID : A list of gene identifiers of length d
SID : A list of sample identifiers of length n
STP : A list of sample descriptions of length d
X   : A dxn array of gene expression values
"""

fname = "../Anchang Charles/GDS1615_full.soft.gz"
with gzip.open(fname) as fid:
    SIF = {}
    for line in fid:
        if line.startswith(line, len("!dataset_table_begin")):
            break
        elif line.startswith(line, len("!subject_description")):
            subset_description = line.split("=")[1].strip()
        elif line.startswith(line, len("!subset_sample_id")):
            subset_ids = [x.strip() for x in subset_ids]
            for k in subset_ids:
                SIF[k] = subset_description
                  #.next().split("\t")
    SID = fid.next().split("\t")
    I = [i for i,x in enumerate(SID) if x.startswith("GSM")]
    SID = [SID[i] for i in I]
    STP = [SIF[k] for k in SID]
```

I get an error message which says

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Anchang Charles/new affymetrix.py', wdir='C:/Users/Anchang Charles')

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Anchang Charles/new affymetrix.py", line 1, in 
    from affymetrix import X,GID,STP,SID,UC,CD

File "C:\Users\Anchang Charles\affymetrix.py", line 26, in 
    SID = fid.next().split("\t")

AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `iterator.next()` has been replaced with `iterator.__next__()`, but you should be calling it using the built-in `next` function like so:

```
next(iterator)
```

So try:

```
next(fid).split("\t")
```

Read more about it in [PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/)

The crux of the reasoning behind the change:

> The use of double underscores creates a separate namespace for names
>   that are part of the Python language definition, so that programmers
>   are free to create variables, attributes, and methods that start with
>   letters, without fear of silently colliding with names that have a
>   language-defined purpose. (Colliding with reserved keywords is still a
>   concern, but at least this will immediately yield a syntax error.)
>
> The naming of the next method on iterators is an exception to this
>   convention. Code that nowhere contains an explicit call to a next
>   method can nonetheless be silently affected by the presence of such a
>   method. Therefore, this PEP proposes that iterators should have a
>   `__next__` method instead of a `next` method (with no change in semantics).

Comment: thank you for your response...replacing with next(fid).split("\t")                           generates this error message :                                                                             

 StopIteration

Comment: @Charles that has the added bonus of making your code 2/3 compatible...

Comment: replacing with :       fid.__next__().split("\t")               gives:                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 StopIteration

Comment: @Charles do not use `__next__` directly, you should use the built-in function `next`. But it is giving you `StopIteration` because the iterator is exhausted. That's a *different bug*.

Comment: @Charles and that makes sense, since you call it after iterating through the whole file in a for-loop. Not sure what you expect...